# how to send form input values to Empty database which created in local?

Tags: angular, phpmyadmin

I had created a form in html using angular 2.
And I had to save my input files to database( phpmyadmin ).
What can i used to save it in table.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a database **client**, not a database.

Comment: Since you are running PHPMyAdmin, you presumably have PHP and MySQL available to you. Do you have some reason to not want to use them?

Comment: I had created database in my local using phpmyadmin

Comment: @Quentin How can i insert my values into database. I am new to angular 2 but i can't know about node and server side language.

Comment: What does Node have to do with it? Are you planning to use Node instead of PHP? Writing an introduction to server side programming with Node (or PHP) would be too broad a topic for Stackoverflow … as would writing an introduction to using databases with either of them.

Comment: I need using node if u have code send or any other links.

Comment: Like quentin, I would suggest you use PHP and MySQL. How and where have you created the DB, you just say **locally**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to post data from angular 2 client side to server side using http:

```
postData(data: any) {    
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      console.log("Posting data: ", data);

      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "/upload", JSON.stringify(data), options).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This is [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) to official documentation.